# Detecting polarity in a DC device

Tags: dc, polarity

I have a device which can be charged with 5v DC. I wish to locate an adaptor for it, but not knowing the device's polarity, I'm stuck.

Please note: The device requires 5v DC but has no polarity markings.

Without dismantling the device, is there a way of determining its polarity?

TIA.

Comment: Is it something with a metal case where that may be connected to ground? It might help to include more details on the particular device.

Comment: Google for replacement power supplies for that exact device. Look at the pictures for the polarity markings.

Answer (score 1):

> Without dismantling the device,

No true electronics engineer could possibly comprehend what you mean by this part of your question. It's like "without breathing any air for the rest of my life ..."

> is there a way of determining its polarity?

- Look harder, sometimes the polarity symbols are weakly moulded.
- Look for the missing charger under your bed and in the cupboard under the stairs.
- Ditto instruction manual.
- Tell people the exact make and model pf the device.
  (hint: sometimes production runs are >1 unit. someone else might have one)
- Use your google-fu to find a manual.
- Use an endoscope to peek inside and look for electrolytics and other polarised devices
- Use an x-ray machine to plot the PCB traces and identify major components
- Buy (or borrow) another one (identical make and model) with a supplied charger
- Trial and error.

Comment: Center pin is always positive, except in those cases where it is negative.